# What is sed -e expression unknown option to `s`

Tags: sed, terraform, launch-template

I have a EC2 userdata bash script with some sed entries as follows. The userdata was base64 encoded as part of a launch template.

```
sed -i -- "s/{{ data_dir }}/$${CONSUL_DATA_DIR//\//\\\/}/g" $CONSUL_DEFAULT_CONFIG
```

However I’m getting an error when the instance builds with the below:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 39: unknown option to `s'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--` means *end of options, everything following is a file name*. The  substitution `s//` that follows is an option, not a file name. Move the `--` past the substitution argument. Or maybe it's a typo and you should run `sed -i -e "s/.../.../g" $CONSUL_DEFAULT_CONFIG`.

In addition, `$$` will be replaced by the shell by the process ID. Is this taken from a Makefile snippet? Then use just one `$` when running in the shell and not within a make recipe.